# Slowing down a UIView animated entrance

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I have a UIView I'm animating in so that the user can select something and then removing it. Right now I have the following code, and it is really fast. I was wondering if there was a way to slow this down so that it isn't as jaring.

The UIView is not full screen size, but rather about a third in size.

```
        flipOutView.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(new PointF(400, 100), new SizeF(160, 230));
        UIView.BeginAnimations("k");

        flipOutView.Frame = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(new PointF(150, 100), new SizeF(160, 230));

        UIView.CommitAnimations();
```

Also, I'm new to Animations, so are there effects that can be applied? Any good references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIView.SetAnimationDuration(3);

to delay animation to 3 seconds

Answer (score 3):

```
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.5]; // for example
```

also consider the animation profile - for example you could do this as well;

```
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
```

EDIT:

Memo to self, must remember that not everyone writes in Objective-C! OK so the above is for obj-c, but you'll find that monotouch has the same methods available I'm sure.

Comment: Nice, you beat my answer my 18 seconds ;) Though yours is in obj-c and not C#, but I am not nitpicking :)

Comment: Whoops! Saw iPhone and thought obj-c ... you're quite correct!

Comment: I'm getting really good at translating from Obj-c to MonoTouch, so no worries Roger!